# method instance or something onclick

Tags: jquery, html, ipad

i want to change onclick to touch or touchstart because on ipad onclick is not working. i am not getting why it is written like this???this is some object oriented concept or what??

```
  switch ( image.i == my.imageID )
                {
                    case false:
                        image.onclick = function() { 
                        //$('.slideDiv').removeClass('imgnew');                         
                        alert('each time called'+image);
                        my.glideTo(this.i);};
                        break;

                    default:
                        this.zIndex = my.zIndex + 1;
                        if(image.url !== '')
                        {
                            image.onclick = my.onClick;

                        }
                        break;
                }
                image.style.zIndex = my.zIndex;
            }
        }
```

event if i make it onClick  then slso it stop working?? someone suggested this code but it is also not working.

```
$(image).on("touchstart click", function () 
     {
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain what problem you're trying to solve? What do you want to happen if someone clicks an image?

Comment: @Joe on click glide() method is called ... onclick not working in pad so i want to change to touch or touchstart

Comment: @simmisimmi - did u tried using 'touchend'...

Comment: `$(document).on('click vclick tap touchstart, 'img', function` should work.

Comment: @sathish in JS file if i make image.onclick event  onClick it stop working ,don't now why .in html .live('click touchstart touch',   works  but in js it i dont to how to change

Comment: @omar image.click  $(imag).click   nothing working in JS

Comment: in JS `$(document).on('click vclick tap touchstart, 'img', function` works fine.

Comment: @Omar it should be something like image.onclick=function{